# Checking if two variables are equal

Tags: python, input

In my code I'm making a basic multiplying game.

But in my game,

When you get the answer right, it says you got it wrong

Here's my whole code:

```
import random

score = 0
while True:
    num1 = random.choice(range(1,12))
    num2 = random.choice(range(1,12))
    answer = num1 * num2
    a = input("Solve for " + str(num1) + "x" + str(num2))
    if a == answer:
        print("congrats you got it right")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong sorry play again")
        print("Score was: " + str(score))
        break
```

When I get the right answer I get

```
Solve for 7x10 70
Wrong sorry play again
Score was: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other languages might let you get away with this, but Python is strongly typed. The input function gets a string, not a number. Numbers can't be equal to strings. Either convert the number to a string or the string to a number before you compare them. You can use `str` or `int` to convert.

Comment: When I change it to int I get  a = input("Solve for " + int(num1) + "x" + int(num2))
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: I have fixed it, I made it str(a) == str(answer):

Answer (score 1):

Function `input` returns what was typed as a **string**... in order to compare it with the answer, you need to either convert it to `int`:

```
if int(a) == answer:
```

or the other way around (convert answer to `str`):

```
if a == str(answer):
```

The first one may raise an exception if `a` is not parseable to an `int`.
[Here the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

PS: I really wonder how ur random library picked a 1070 sampling from 0 to 11...

Comment: I also wondered that but the case is 7 and 10 is random picked integer and 70 is the input provided to program there is no space thatsy its looking like the number is 1070

Comment: oh i see! you could add `+ " = "` to your input ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or use `int(input())`:

```
import random

score = 0
while True:
    num1 = random.choice(range(1,12))
    num2 = random.choice(range(1,12))
    answer = num1 * num2
    a = int(input("Solve for " + str(num1) + "x" + str(num2)))
    if a == answer:
        print("congrats you got it right")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong sorry play again")
        print("Score was: " + str(score))
        break
```